# what's the difference between mysql 2.8.1 and ruby-mysql 2.9.3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Some plugin works well in mysql gem but doesn't works so well in ruby-mysql

in rubygems, mysql gem has 453,540 total downloads, and ruby-mysql only has 12,137
total downloads.

I wanna know what's the difference between them.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the difference is 0.1.2 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference can be seen at the project's [commit log](https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/commits/master), enjoy.